# Background image disappears when viewed on iPhone

Tags: html, css, responsive

We are currently copying airbnb.
The top image does not disappear even if I check the responsive view on Mac, but the image disappears when I check it on iPhone.

[image][image]

Tried: I used `background-size:cover` and tried `height:0` and `padding-top:60%`.

If you know how to fix it, please tell us.

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you want to add the code?

Comment: I don't want to but you should :)